# how to find out the directory path of the frontend in Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, directory, electron, filesystems

I have made an offline app with Electron. I already use `window.showDirectoryPicker()` but it just returns:

```
{
  kind: 'directory',   
  name: 'New Folder'
}
```

With the code below, after I select a folder then the `inpFile` value remains empty.

```html
<input type="file" id='inpFile' webkitdirectory directory>
```

```js
inpFile.value = e.target.files[0].path
```

What should I do in order to find out the directory path of the folder I have selected?